# Why does HTMLDocument ignore white spaces

Tags: java, swing, whitespace, htmleditorkit

I have a problem. It looks like that `HTMLEditorKit` just ignore white spaces. There is my sample code:

```
public class TestEditor extends JFrame {

public TestEditor(){
    createConnection();
    createGUI();
}
private void createGUI(){
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JScrollPane scroll1=new JScrollPane(text);
    JScrollPane scroll2=new JScrollPane(html);
    JSplitPane split=new JSplitPane();
    split.setLeftComponent(scroll1);
    split.setRightComponent(scroll2);
    split.setDividerLocation(0.5);
    split.setResizeWeight(0.5);
    getContentPane().add(split);
    setTitle("Test");
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,300));
    pack();
}
private void createConnection(){
    text=new JTextPane();
    html=new JTextPane();
    html.setContentType("text/html");
    html.getStyledDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            update();
        }
        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            update();
        }
        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            update();
        }
        private void update(){
            if(fromText) return;
            fromHtml=true;
            text.setText(html.getText());
            fromHtml=false;
        }
    });
    text.getStyledDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            update();
        }
        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            update();
        }
        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            update();
        }
        private void update(){
            if(fromHtml) return;
            fromText=true;
            html.setText(text.getText());
            fromText=false;
        }
    });
}
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new TestEditor().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
private JTextPane text;
private JTextPane html;
private boolean fromHtml, fromText;
}
```

This code creates a simple application containing two `JTextPane` text fields. User is allowed to write in the right editor and then he can see a HTML code on the left side. Additionally, he can edit the code and see the changes on the right side.

There is the problem. Let's assume that I wrote the text

```
"     aaaa"
```

in the right editor (five spaces before "aaaa"). This would present itself well. However if I add next 'a' in HTML editor (on the left side) I lose my 5 spaces and see only "aaaaa" on the right side.

Is there any way to fix this problem, so that my 5 spaces wouldn't be lost?

Comment: Because that's how HTML works

Comment: Have you tried with the `<pre>` tag?

Comment: I know that this is the HTML behaviour, however I would like to know is there any way to "fix" it as I want :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTML strips all tabs, spaces and makes them in a single space.

The HTML code/entity for a space is `&nbsp;` and for a tab `&#09;`

If you wish to preserve all spaces when double space is used you could consider using this:

```
String spaces = text.getText()
                .replace("  ","&nbsp;&nbsp;")
                .replace("\t","&#09;");
html.setText(spaces);
```

This way you replace tabs for `&#09;` HTML entity, and double spaces for two HTML spaces. Single spaces will be left alone as they will render properly.

Comment: FYI: That's actually called an HTML entity.

Answer (score 2):

Probably because it does not recognize the character space, but sees it as empty spaces. You can change it to `&nbsp;`, which is the HTML-code for a space.

Answer (score 1):

Use `<![CDATA[     aaaa]]>`
and also loop up https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
html.setText(text.getText().replace("  ","&nbsp;"));
```